# how to solve apparmor "profile transition not found"

Tags: apparmor

I get repeated apparmor messages like the following in my syslog (profile is in complain mode):

```
Aug 29 02:07:13 titan kernel: [19497.559718] audit: type=1400 audit(1472454433.147:1131): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="exec" info="**profile transition not found**" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/dovecot" name="/usr/lib/dovecot/anvil" pid=5983 comm="dovecot" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0 target="/usr/lib/dovecot/anvil"
```

What needs to be added to the usr.bin.dovecot profile to address this? aa-logprof finds nothing.

The profile **already** has this line, which I though addressed this:

```
/usr/lib/dovecot/anvil rPx,
```